# What are semantic differences between Python 2.7 and 3.3?

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.3

I have a fairly sizable project that I wrote. I run it with Python 3.3 and it works.

If I run it with 2.7, there is no complaint about the syntax, but the program does not work (the output is not what is expected).

I don't expect anyone to look through a few thousand lines of code to help me find the difference. I just want to know where I can find a list of things that are syntactically valid in 2.7 and 3.3 but semantically different. Because of the large number of differences between Python versions, I except that I should be able to find something that will help me.

I used generators and corountines heavily. Other than that, there is nothing fancy (no introspection, etc.).

I realize this is broad and lacks code; I just am at somewhat of a loss about how to learn the difference (and I don't think looking through that much poorly documented code will help anyone).

EDIT: But, in case I'm wrong, it's at https://github.com/paulddraper/internet-simulator.
It simulates TCP connections (started as school project). I used corountines to be able to write functions as if they were multi-threaded. Anyway, if a run `main.py` from within `src/` with Python 3.3, I get different output than if I run it with Python 2.7.

Comment: I would start by adding `print` statements in critical parts of the code. You need to narrow down the problem.

Comment: Yes...I am doing that (sigh). I don't have a good debugger, and the corountines make the flow non-trivial.

Comment: Can you post the code (or a link to it) here? Maybe someone can spot something problematic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it.

To get Python 3's division behavior, I need to add `from __future__ import division` when in 2.7.

I knew that already, but for some reason it didn't come to mind when I tried to think of the semantic differences.